# Read C++ QString binary data with PHP

Tags: php, c++, qt, binary

I have to read a binary file written by a C++ app using Qt framework. Data is structured from a C struct as described below. Chars are written from a QString pointer in the C++ app.

```
struct panelSystem{
    char ipAddress[16];
    char netMask[16];
    char gateway[16];
    char paddingBytes[128];
};
```

I tried using the following PHP code to read the multibyte char values :

```
    // Where: $length is a defined number (16 or 128 in this case)
    //        $data is a binary string read from the binary file

    $var = substr($data, $currentOffset, $length);
    $currentOffset += $length;    // Increment offset by X bytes
    $var = trim(str_replace("\0", "\n", $var));
    $var = unpack("C*", $var);
    $char = '';
    foreach ($var as $letter) {
        $char .= chr($letter);
    }
    $var = $char;
```

Unfortunately the result includes null (\0) and/or irrelevant characters before and after the desired char.

Is there a way to interpret or convert those char from QString multibyte array to PHP standard string (without modifying the original input) ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A QString will be written to the binary with (at least) a length value and the character data.  You also will need to take into account how the string is formatted.  It might be in unicode utf-16, in which case, simple chars will have each character padded with zeros.  Where the zeros go will depend upon what endian-ness the file is written in, though IIRC Qt will always store files in one particular endian-ness, regardless of the platform so that binaries are cross platform.

Have a look in the Qt source code to see how strings are written.  Maybe also take a look at the binary file in a hex editor.

If your binary file only ever contains the struct, and you don't have a problem with the binary format being fixed, then you may find things far easier to write the file using raw IO:

```
struct panelSystem{
    char ipAddress[16];
    char netMask[16];
    char gateway[16];
    char paddingBytes[128];

    void write(QDataStream& ds) {
        ds.writeRawData(ipAddress, sizeof(ipAddress));
        ds.writeRawData(netMask, sizeof(netMask));
        ds.writeRawData(gateway, sizeof(gateway));
        ds.writeRawData(paddingBytes, sizeof(paddingBytes));
    }
};

//...

    panelSystem p;
    GetPanelSystemData(&p);

    QFile file("c:\\work\\test\\testbin.bin");
    if (file.open(QIODevice::Truncate | QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
        QDataStream ds(&file);
        p.write(ds);        
    }
    file.close();
```

I would recommend at least adding a version number/header to the start binary file to prevent painting yourself into a corner.